# Cubic hypersurface of singular conics

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Conics in $\mathbb{P}^2$ are in one to one correspondence with points in $\mathbb{P}^5$, simple enough. Conics of rank one i.e. double lines are in a one to one correspondence with points on the Veronese surface in $\mathbb{P}^5$, this is also clear to me. Now I read that all singular conics in $\mathbb{P}^2$ (i.e. rank 1 or 2) somehow correspond to a cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^5$. I also read that this cubic hypersuface has something to do with the secants lines of the Veronese surface, which I also don't follow. Could you clarify this last correspondance for me?

Comment: Dear @user198182 , I can't write all the details now, but could this hypersurface be defined by the Jacobi matrix of the "universal" conic? For a conic given by $a= (a_0:\ldots:a_5)$ to be singular it is necessary and suffices for the Jacobi matrix of the associated quadric to be of rank zero. If $f_{a}(x,y,z)$ is the associated quadric, then this translates into the vanishing of the discriminant of $f_{a}$ probably. I wrote this in a hurry, so probably someone else could correct/complement this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space of conics in $\mathbf P^2$ can be thought of as the space of symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices $M$, modulo scalars, and the rank of a conic $C$ is exactly the rank of a corresponding matrix $M$. (There is a 1-parameter family of such $M$ for a given $C$, but they are all multiples of each other, so the rank is well-defined.)

So the hypersurface of singular conics is exactly

$$ \{ \operatorname{det} M =0 \} \subset \mathbf P^5.$$

The determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix is a homogeneous cubic polynomial in the entries, so this is a cubic hypersurface.

Now for the second part: a point on the secant variety of the Veronese surface can be thought of as a linear combination of two matrices of rank 1 (again, modulo scalars). It's not hard to see that such a matrix has rank at most 2. So the secant variety of the Veronese surface is contained in the determinant hypersurface. On the other hand, one can show that *any*  matrix of rank 2 is a linear combination of two rank-1 matrices (say by using projective transformations to diagonalise the rank-2 matrix). So actually the secant variety is equal to the determinant hypersurface.